# IE8 Inventing margins in divs

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, margins

I have a very simple page consisting of many divs floating left and top of each others.

Just like a table.

In each div, there is a gif or jpeg image, exactly the same size as the div itself.

In all browsers except IE8 ( I tested all the other, more recent browsers, including the current version of Explorer ), it works just fine.

In IE8, the browser invents vertical margins everywhere. So it deconstructs my entire page.

Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
$serveur = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
<html>
<head><title>Test Microsite</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: ffcc99;">

<div id='wrapper' style='width: 1280; margin: 0 auto; box-shadow: 80px 80px 50px #888888;'>
    <!--
    <div style='width: 100%; height: 25; background-color: black;'>
    </div> -->
    <div id="top-1" style='width: 180; height: 40; float:left; background-color: gray; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Top-1.gif" width="180" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="top-2" style='width: 920; height: 40; float:left; background-color: green; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Top-2.gif" width="920" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="top-3" style='width: 180; height: 40; float:left; background-color: blue; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Top-3.gif" width="180" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="gauche-principal" style='width: 180; height: 660; float:left; background-color: gray; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <img src="images/Gauche-Principal.gif" width="180" height="660" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="centre-principal" style='width: 660; height: 660; float:left; background-image: url("images/Centre-principal.jpg"); display: block;'>
        <center>Votre adresse IP est: <br><?php echo $ip;?></center><br><br><br>
        <center>Si vous êtes un visiteur de l'agence, l'image ci-jointe sera noire et bleue.<br>Autrement, l'image sera rouge et noire.<br>
        <?php
            if ( $ip == "142.85.5.166" || $ip == "142.85.5.167" || $ip == "142.85.5.168" || $ip == "142.83.68.66" )
            {?>
                <img src="http://sol.heimsnet.is/!Jolamappan/wreath-blue-square.jpg">
            <?php }
            else {?>
                <img src="http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/108811/adhorrence-red-black-design.gif">
            <?php };
        ?>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div id="barre-boutons" style='width: 260; height: 660; float:left; background-color: violet; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Barre-boutons-1.gif" width="260" height="260" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-2.gif" width="260" height="20" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-3.gif" width="260" height="80" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-4.gif" width="260" height="8" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-5.gif" width="260" height="80" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-6.gif" width="260" height="8" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-7.gif" width="260" height="80" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-8.gif" width="260" height="8" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-9.gif" width="260" height="80" alt="">
    <img src="images/Barre-boutons-10.gif" width="260" height="36" alt="">

    </div>
    <div id="droite-principal" style='width: 180; height: 660; float:left; background-color: orange; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Droite-principal.png" width="180" height="660" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="gauche-barre-bas" style='width: 180; height: 40; float:left; background-color: blue; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Gauche-barre-bas.gif" width="180" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="centre-barre-bas" style='width: 920; height: 40; float:left; background-color: red; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Centre-barre-bas.gif" width="920" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="droite-barre-bas" style='width: 180; height: 40; float:left; background-color: blue; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Droite-barre-bas.gif" width="180" height="40" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="gauche-footer" style='width: 180; height: 80; float:left; background-color: gray; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Gauche-footer.gif" width="180" height="80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="centre-footer" style='width: 920; height: 80; float:left; background-color: orange; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Centre-footer.gif" width="920" height="80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="droite-footer" style='width: 180; height: 80; float:left; background-color: pink; display: block;'>
        <img src="images/Droite-footer.jpg" width="180" height="80" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

These are the results:

In standard browsers ( you know, the ones that actually works.. )
http://www.martinbeaulne.com/temp/test-microsite/site-exemple-CHROME.jpg

IE8 ( yeah, some people really use this, as strange as it may seem )
http://www.martinbeaulne.com/temp/test-microsite/site-exemple-IE8.jpg

( the colors come from each div's background. It's a markup I've put to see what's happening. )

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Other than telling people to use a real browser? Some people back on WinXP might have trouble moving to IE10+ (some are probably still blissfully using IE6!), but they can use the latest FF, Chrome, etc. There comes a point where you simply have to cut loose people who refuse to use a decent browser. Have you tried explicitly setting **margin: 0;** in your CSS? Does IE8 not follow inheritance rules? If so, what about specifying top/bottom margins on all divs?

Comment: If you’re not even setting a Doctype, you have no right or reason to complain about _any_ rendering errors.

Comment: I tried lots of margin:0 things.
In the wrapper, in all the divs, trying margin-bottom:0 or margin:0

But, most of all, as I read your answers, I see it is not a "recurrent" problem ? I thought people would answer things like:"Yeah, it's a well known problem with anciant IE browsers...".

CBroe: I tried some doctype tags, and it worsened the page. 
I'd be glad to try your suggestion of doctype syntax. Do you really think setting the doctype would help, for such a basic thing ?

Tried some things. Can't find a solution. 

Any other ideas ?